# Check which number is bigger within a function call - vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Say I'm using this piece of code

```
With TextBox
.Size = New Windows.Size(InsideRadius)
End With
```

I want to choose within the function call which size to use dependent on which is the biggest, If Inside Radius is the biggest then choose that, but if a number such as say 20 is bigger then pick that, all within the call.

So something like this

```
With TextBox
.Size = New Windows.Size(If (InsideRadius >= 20) Then InsideRadius Else 20 End If)
End With
```

but I'm unsure how to do this within vb.net, I'm sure it is possible but after some searching I think I'm not typing in the correct question to get what I am looking for. Hope you understand, thanks

Comment: Is InsideRadius a Size?  It should be.  Are you wanting width or height?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.size?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Size

Comment: Is this vba? vb.net and vba are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, it looks like a function that is called if:

`If(Statement, True, False)`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/if-operator

Answer (score 0):

Math.Max()

```
Math.Max(InsideRadius, 20)
```

This will return whichever is the larger number.

```
TextBox.Size = New Windows.Size(Math.Max(InsideRadius, 20)
```